# Spring JPA @Query with expression

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to make a method in custom repository with example query:

```
@Query("select e from Entity e where :#{@customService.myWhereLogic(#e) is not null}")
```

where customService.myWhereLogic() this my spring bean whith some method. I need to argument myWhereLogic() method's is not null when execute query. How do it(now null, but result query not 0 count)?

Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, maybe you can enhance your post a little because it's hard to figure out what the question is about. Anyway, I will try to answer.

Invoking methods on passed query parameter objects via SpEL is possible in general, but for multiple reasons it's not a good idea in this case.

It seems your intention is that the service method should somehow replace a where clause, right? But what should it return to satisfy the SQL syntax? Even it would return a column name / value combination or similar to create valid statement, that won't work, because prepared statement parameters are only allowed for column values, neither for columns nor tables. That can only be achieved via plain string concatenation, but that's in general a bad idea within SQL statements.

Your approach would return an invalid SQL statement like:

`select e from Entity e where 'yourResult'`

And even if it would work, coupling your query and the service like this feels not right.

If you really want to "enhance" your Repositories with business code, try to implement that with [Specifications](https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/) like:

```
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery;
import javax.persistence.criteria.JoinType;
import javax.persistence.criteria.Predicate;
import javax.persistence.criteria.Root;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.example.model.YourEntity;
import com.example.service.YourService;

@Component
public class SomeSpecification implements Specification<YourEntity> {

    @Autowired
    private YourService yourService;

    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(final Root<YourEntity> yourEntity, final CriteriaQuery<?> query, final CriteriaBuilder builder) {

        return null; // implement your business checks with yourService and some matchers
    }

}
```